# enquiry on performance boost/hit for centralized source code location

Tags: iis, storage, website, version-control

My website currently has multiple windows servers , all of them local in intranet, and each of them have the same source code in the same folder. Currently my workflow is every time I want to *Live* a new feature, I have to copy and paste to each of those servers. It's getting tedious now since I have around 10 servers, and there have been cases of my colleagues and I missing a server.

We have been looking at separate centralized clustered storage (like Gluster) to store the source code, and we just upload to one point and it will propagate, and we just link it through shared folder in microsoft IIS.

My questions are :

1. Is there any benefit to doing this? or is it only going to make the website slow?
2. If it's making the website slower, is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks, I appreciate your time reading or responding to my post.

Comment: You can find tons of previous discussions that reveal what factors might matter in the final performance of your specific web apps. But there isn't a silver bullet for all web apps, so people usually end up with their own baseline testing and decisions. Threads like https://serverfault.com/questions/125549/iis7-web-farm-local-or-shared-content and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695782/whats-so-bad-about-running-an-iis-web-application-from-an-unc-share-as-suggest can be easily found from search engines.

Comment: Thanks for commenting mate, I read the posts and it's interesting, maybe I used the wrong keyword for searching in the past, since quite honestly I don't know what I need yet (the Gluster part was initially for storing DB backup).

Thanks again, appreciate your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any benefit to doing this?

Yes. 1 POF is better than 10

> or is it only going to make the website slow?

- *Maybe slower* than with local storage
- I, personally, prefer to avoid Windows-shares in Production

I think, fully *automagic* CD, which deploy (on conditions met) from single central point to all IIS-hosts may be more bullet-proof solution

NB: I'm far away from **real** server-management for decades

Comment: by automagic i assume you meant automatic continuous depoloyment? like gitlab/github?

Comment: @hafwan - yes, I tried to add some piece of joke into long dull text of obvious things

Comment: not gonna lie I chuckled a bit when i got it.  Yeah thanks to your input, I think I got a clearer direction on where to go, since a few more focused Google search led me to Jenkins. I hope I can proceed well. Thanks mate.